# Calculate mouse position from bottom right of window?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm writing some jQuery to check if the mouse is near the bottom or right of a window and reposition a tooltip accordingly. This is important as the table on which these tooltips appear is larger than the 'viewport'

Something like this would work only if all screens were the same size:

```
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  $( "#log" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );
});
```

**How can I count with the bottom right as '0x0'?**

Comment: If you're calculating from window, why does screen size matter?

Comment: Because different monitors will give you different x and y coordinates

Comment: @Jonny they don't, they ask on StackOverflow ..

Comment: @blarg That's not true. 10 from bottom and 10 from the right is the same in every window no matter the screen size, which is why I asked why does it matter since you're using the window as reference.

Comment: @Hacketo Who are you talking to?

Comment: @blarg someone who delete his comment.

Answer (score 3):

Subtract the `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` from window's `width` and `height` respectively, if you want to get the co-ordinates with respect to the bottom right corner.

```js
$(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
  $("#log").text("pageX: " + ($(window).width() - event.pageX) + ", pageY: " + ($(window).height() -event.pageY));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Substract the window width from your coordinates:

```js
$(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
  var winWidth = $(window).width();
  var winHeight = $(window).height();

  console.log(
   "pageX: " + (winWidth - event.pageX),     
   "pageY: " + (winHeight - event.pageY) 
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to figure the width and height of the window and then find the difference between the mouse position and those vars.

This should solve your problem:

```
    $( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
// breakdown of variables
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    var posFromRight = w-event.pageX;
    var posFromBottom = h-event.pageY;

// then use them to position your tooltip
    $('.tooltip').css({
          "position": 'absolute',
          "bottom": posFromBottom,
    "right": posFromRight
        });
    });
```